# Recursively find only directories with files using Finder in Symfony

Tags: filter, directory, symfony, finder

I am building a script to import image sets. Each imageset is contained in a directory but the depth of the deepest directory is unknown. It could be 1, 2, 3, 4 or more.

Now I want to use the Symfony Finder component to get a list of the deepest directories. So I can filter out the images in that directory and group them.

Or maybe a better solution would be to filter out all images using:

```
$files = Finder::create()
    ->in($path)
    ->files()
    ->date('until 1 hour ago')
    ->name('/\.(' . implode('|', $this->extensions) . ')$/')
    ->exclude('.gitignore');
```

But now I have an array with all the images but I need to group them bij their deepest directory so that I have a multidimensional array with as key the deepest directory. For example:

```
[
    '/path1/path2' => ['/path1/path2/img1', '/path1/path2/img2', ...],
    '/path1/path3/path4' => ['/path1/path3/path4/img3', '/path1/path3/path4/img4', ...],
    ...
]
```